# Is there a way to use my USB web Camera which I use with my windows PC to use with my iPad first edition?

Tags: ipad, windows, camera, webcam, chat

Is there a way to use my USB web Camera which I use with my windows PC to use with my iPad first edition?

Or any other camera to use with ipad first edition.

Comment: Vyas: You should accept your answers if you are going to ask so many questions. People will be more inclined to answer and you will get higher quality answers as well if people know they will be rewarded for their effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iPad does not support using external cameras with it, as it does not have the drivers required.

Thus, the iPad cannot use an external camera. However, the new iPad 2 has cameras.